# Batch File Why does it keeps cycling thru all variables?

Tags: string, variables, batch-file, echo

> I wanted to make my own music player because im **tired** of *Spotify* and all of those *ads*

::When i play a song it will say *Now playing then the song* but it will then begin to cycle thru all the names ?

::***This is what i got going on so far***

```
@echo off
title Rainbow Music
cls
color 0b
cls
echo This program was created by tsgsOFFICIAL
choice /n /c yn /t 2 /d y >nul
cls
color 07
cls

:PAC
cls
echo Please pick a color and enter it down below!
echo.
echo Type 1 for Blue text
echo Type 2 for Green text
echo Type 3 for Cyan text
echo Type 4 for Red text
echo Type 5 for Purple text
echo Type 6 for Yellow text
echo Type 7 for White text
echo Type 8 for Gray text
echo Type 9 for Light Blue text
echo Type a for Light Green text
echo Type b for Light Cyan
echo Type c for Light Red
echo Type d for Light Purple
echo Type e for Light Yellow
echo Type f for Bright White
echo.
set /p colorID=Enter ColorID: 
if %colorID%==1 goto 1
if %colorID%==2 goto 2
if %colorID%==3 goto 3
if %colorID%==4 goto 4
if %colorID%==5 goto 5
if %colorID%==6 goto 6
if %colorID%==7 goto 7
if %colorID%==8 goto 8
if %colorID%==9 goto 9
if %colorID%==a goto a
if %colorID%==b goto b
if %colorID%==c goto c
if %colorID%==d goto d
if %colorID%==e goto e
if %colorID%==f goto f

:1
cls
color 1
goto start

:2
cls
color 2
goto start

:3
cls
color 3
goto start

:4
cls
color 4
goto start

:5
cls
color 5
goto start

:6
cls
color 6
goto start

:7
cls
color 7
goto start

:8
cls
color 8
goto start

:9
cls
color 9
goto start

:a
cls
color a
goto start

:b
cls
color b
goto start

:c
cls
color c
goto start

:d
cls
color d
goto start

:e
cls
color e
goto start

:f
cls
color f
goto start

:start
cls
echo Do you wish to enable auto mode?
set /p auto=
if %auto%==yes goto auto
if %auto%==no goto manual

:auto
cls
echo Great!
echo.
echo Now pick a song to start it off.
echo.
echo Type 1 for Avicii - Hey Brother
echo Type 2 for Maroon 5 - Maps
echo Type 3 for Tove Lo - Cool Girl
echo Type 4 for Maroon 5 - Animals
echo Type 5 for David Guetta - Play Hard
echo.
set /p songID=Enter songID: 
if %songID%==1 goto Auto1
if %songID%==2 goto Auto2
if %songID%==3 goto Auto3
if %songID%==4 goto Auto4
if %songID%==5 goto Auto5
```

> **this is where i put the variables below**

```
set song1=Avicii - Hey Brother
set song2=Maroon 5 - Maps
set song3=Tove Lo - Cool Girl
set song4=Maroon 5 - Animals
set song5=David Guetta - Play Hard

:Auto1
cls
start  C:\Users\tsgsO\Downloads\Songs\"Avicii - Hey Brother.mp3"
set /a x=248

:POSSA1
if %x%==1 goto POSA1
if %x% gtr 0 (
echo Now playing %song1%
echo.
echo %x% Seconds
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
set /a x-=1
cls
goto POSSA1
)

:POSA1
if %x% gtr 0 (
echo Now playing %song1%
echo.
echo %x% Second
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
set /a x-=1
cls
goto POSSA1
)
:Auto2
cls
start  C:\Users\tsgsO\Downloads\Songs\"Maroon 5 - Maps.mp3"
set /a x=190

:POSSA2
if %x%==1 goto POSA2
if %x% gtr 0 (
echo Now playing %song2%
echo.
echo %x% Seconds
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
set /a x-=1
cls
goto POSSA2
)

:POSA2
if %x% gtr 0 (
echo Now playing %song2%
echo.
echo %x% Second
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
set /a x-=1
cls
goto POSSA2
)

:Auto3
cls
start  C:\Users\tsgsO\Downloads\Songs\"Tove Lo - Cool Girl.mp3"
set /a x=196

:POSSA3
if %x%==1 goto POSA3
if %x% gtr 0 (
echo Now playing %song3%
echo.
echo %x% Seconds
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
set /a x-=1
cls
goto POSSA3
)

:POSA3
if %x% gtr 0 (
echo Now playing %song3%
echo.
echo %x% Second
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
set /a x-=1
cls
goto POSSA3
)

:Auto4
cls
start  C:\Users\tsgsO\Downloads\Songs\"Maroon 5 - Animals.mp3"
set /a x=227

:POSSA4
if %x%==1 goto POSA4
if %x% gtr 0 (
echo Now playing %song4%
echo.
echo %x% Seconds
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
set /a x-=1
cls
goto POSSA4
)

:POSA4
if %x% gtr 0 (
echo Now playing %song4%
echo.
echo %x% Second
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
set /a x-=1
cls
goto POSSA4
)

:Auto5
cls
start  C:\Users\tsgsO\Downloads\Songs\"David Guetta - Play Hard.mp3"
set /a x=222

:POSSA5
if %x%==1 goto POSA5
if %x% gtr 0 (
echo Now playing %song5%
echo.
echo %x% Seconds
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
set /a x-=1
cls
goto POSSA5
)

:POSA5
if %x% gtr 0 (
echo Now playing %song5%
echo.
echo %x% Second
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
set /a x-=1
cls
goto POSSA5
)
goto Auto1

:manual
cls
echo Great
echo.
echo Now pick a song to play!
echo.
echo Type 1 for Avicii - Hey Brother
echo Type 2 for Maroon 5 - Maps
echo Type 3 for Tove Lo - Cool Girl
echo Type 4 for Maroon 5 - Animals
echo Type 5 for David Guetta - Play Hard
echo.
set /p songID=Enter songID: 
if %songID%==1 goto Manual1
if %songID%==2 goto Manual2
if %songID%==3 goto Manual3
if %songID%==4 goto Manual4
if %songID%==5 goto Manual5

:Manual1
cls
start  C:\Users\tsgsO\Downloads\Songs\"Avicii - Hey Brother.mp3"
set /a x=248

:POSSM1
if %x%==1 goto POSM1
if %x% gtr 0 (
echo Now playing %song1%
echo.
echo %x% Seconds
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
set /a x-=1
cls
goto POSSM1S
)

:POSM1
if %x% gtr 0 (
echo Now playing %song1%
echo.
echo %x% Second
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
set /a x-=1
cls
goto POSSM1S
)
goto close

:Manual2
cls
start  C:\Users\tsgsO\Downloads\Songs\"Maroon 5 - Maps.mp3"
set /a x=190

:POSSM2S
if %x%==1 goto POSM2
if %x% gtr 0 (
echo Now playing %song2%
echo.
echo %x% Seconds
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
set /a x-=1
cls
goto POSSM2S
)

:POSM2
if %x% gtr 0 (
echo Now playing %song2%
echo.
echo %x% Second
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
set /a x-=1
cls
goto POSSM2
)
goto close

:Manual3
cls
start  C:\Users\tsgsO\Downloads\Songs\"Tove Lo - Cool Girl.mp3"
set /a x=196

:POSSM3
if %x%==1 goto POSM3
if %x% gtr 0 (
echo Now playing %song3%
echo.
echo %x% Seconds
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
set /a x-=1
cls
goto POSSM3
)

:POSM3
if %x% gtr 0 (
echo Now playing %song3%
echo.
echo %x% Second
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
set /a x-=1
cls
goto POSSM3
)
goto close

:Manual4
cls
start  C:\Users\tsgsO\Downloads\Songs\"Maroon 5 - Animals.mp3"
set /a x=227

:POSSM4
if %x%==1 goto POSM4
if %x% gtr 0 (
echo Now playing %song4%
echo.
echo %x% Seconds
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
set /a x-=1
cls
goto POSSM4
)

:POSM4
if %x% gtr 0 (
echo Now playing %song4%
echo.
echo %x% Second
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
set /a x-=1
cls
goto POSSM4
)
goto close

:Manual5
cls
start  C:\Users\tsgsO\Downloads\Songs\"David Guetta - Play Hard.mp3"
set /a x=222

:POSSM5
if %x%==1 goto POSM5
if %x% gtr 0 (
echo Now playing %song5%
echo.
echo %x% Seconds
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
set /a x-=1
cls
goto POSSM5
)

:POSM5
if %x% gtr 0 (
echo Now playing %song5%
echo.
echo %x% Second
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
set /a x-=1
cls
goto POSSM5
)
goto close

:close
taskkill /f /IM WMPlayer.exe
cls
echo Successfully ended the song
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
echo.
echo Do you want to play another song?
set /p newsong=
if %newsong%==yes goto manual
if %newsong%==no goto exit

:stop
taskkill /F /IM WMPlayer.exe
cls
echo Successfully ended the song
echo.
choice /n /c ys /t 1 /d y >nul
echo Do you want to end the player?
set /p exit=
if %exit%==yes goto exit
if %exit%==no goto Auto

:exit
cls
echo Okay Bye!
choice /n /c yn /t 1 /d y >nul
EXIT
```

Comment: In Example 1, you are simply overwriting the variable value. Your question is quite unclear; as far as I understand it, you have the following options: 1. concatenating the string to one using a certain delimiter character (this could be also a line-break); 2. treating the variables from example 2 as (pseudo-)arrays, so the numeric part in their names (`song1`) is considered as the index of the array element. Please clarify what you want!

Comment: Please do not change the scope of your question, particularly because there was already an answer, which may become invalid then! And read this help topic: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Comment: Okay, so i will change this back to how it was and make a new one, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop:

```
FOR %%f IN ('song1 song2 song3') DO echo Now Playing %%f
```

This will split the string on each space. This is controllable though. See http://ss64.com/nt/for.html

You can also use something like

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%f IN ('dir /b *.mp3') DO echo Now Playing %%f
```

Which will execute `dir /b *.mp3` to list all mp3s in the directory and then do something to them

Comment: Remove the apostrophies from the first `for` loop as they become parts of the strings otherwise...